# How to jquery hover an element that has display: none;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I got a slider which has a couple of anchor elements (with **.rslides_nav.next** & **.rslides_nav.prev**) to recreate arrows and allow user to navigate. I must make these arrows invisible until the user is on:hover on the slider. So I use display: none.

EDIT to put the solution: It is not possible to hover on an element that has `display: none;` better use `visibility: hidden;` as suggested in the accepted answer.

CSS:

```
.rslides_nav.next {
    display: none;
}

.rslides_nav.prev {
    display: none;
}
```

And then I add the class mostrar_navs via Jquery with:

```
 $('#metaslider').hover(
      function(){
        $('.rslides_nav.next').addClass('mostrar_navs'),
        $('.rslides_nav.prev').addClass('mostrar_navs')
      },

      function(){
        $('.rslides_nav.next').removeClass('mostrar_navs'),
        $('.rslides_nav.prev').removeClass('mostrar_navs')
      }
    );
```

And this css:

```
.mostrar_navs {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Everything works fine until I hover the arrows (anchor). It starts to appear and disappear, so I used the following jquery.hover() which doesn't work:

```
  $('.rslides_nav').hover(
      function(){
        $('.rslides_nav.next').addClass('mostrar_navs'),
        $('.rslides_nav.prev').addClass('mostrar_navs')
      },

      function(){
        $('.rslides_nav.next').removeClass('mostrar_navs'),
        $('.rslides_nav.prev').removeClass('mostrar_navs')
      }
  );
```

Any idea to solve the problem?

**EDIT TO ADD HTML:**

```
<div id="metaslider_container_133">
    <ul id="metaslider_133" class="rslides rslides1">
        <li id="rslides1_s0" class="" style="display: block; float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;"><img src="http://micubo.kevinmamaqi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/xSLIDER-01.02.jpg.pagespeed.ic.dIb-wgR5PQ.webp" height="700" width="1600" alt="" class="slider-133 slide-164"></li>
        <li style="float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;" id="rslides1_s1" class=""><img src="http://micubo.kevinmamaqi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/xSLIDER-02.02.jpg.pagespeed.ic.r1uBWZHLRw.webp" height="700" width="1600" alt="" class="slider-133 slide-167"></li>
        <li style="float: left; position: relative; opacity: 1; z-index: 2; display: list-item; transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;" id="rslides1_s2" class="rslides1_on"><img src="http://micubo.kevinmamaqi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/xSLIDER-03.02.jpg.pagespeed.ic.obhEqWfXEJ.webp" height="700" width="1600" alt="" class="slider-133 slide-168"></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="rslides_nav rslides1_nav prev mostrar_navs">&lt;</a>
    <a href="#" class="rslides_nav rslides1_nav next mostrar_navs">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't hover over an element that isn't displayed. Use `visibility: hidden` instead.

Comment: Also as a side comment, it would be cleaner to implement the hover effect purely in CSS instead of toggling classes with jQuery.

Comment: I'm guessing the arrows aren't inside the slide you're hovering, and when the mouse is over the arrows it effectively leaves the slide, triggering the mouseleave event, which removes the class, until they are hidden, then the mouseenter event fires again, and on it goes. It's a common problem. Either put the arrows inside the elements for the slider, or post the HTML here to get some help.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you, it was that the arrows where out of the selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make object invisible doesn't mean put them

```
display: none;
```

Try with it

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//On hover tag hide img1 and show img2    

.img2 {
        display:none;
    }
    
    .img1:hover + .img2 {
        transition-duration:0s;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).